# variable in for loop has different values in the same loop (C language)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

In these loops i has two different values and I don't know why it's that, as I'm not increasing it's size. I'm printing i in both loops, but it has a greater value when printed inside the inner loop and the value it should have in the extern one.

Edit: the description erased, I rewrote it with only relevant information.

Can you tell me why this happens?

```
int position = 0;
int size = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < position; j++)
    {
        printf("    i = %d\n", i);
    }

    position++;

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
}

printf("\n");
```

This is what it prints:

```
i = 0
    i = 1
i = 1
    i = 2
    i = 2
i = 2
    i = 3
    i = 3
    i = 3
i = 3
```

While the desired output should be:

```
i = 0
i = 1
    i = 1
i = 2
    i = 2
    i = 2
i = 3
    i = 3
    i = 3
    i = 3
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and add your desired output? Also, what is the value of `position`?

Comment: I'm asumming the first line of the output is *not* indented?

Comment: _This program is supposed to print a certain character  ?_ To print a character in `C` you need to use `%c` format specifier but I'm not seeing that in shown example. Please add the complete code if its not too big

Comment: Can't reproduce *after putting a proper wrapping code around it*. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. Edit: the code and the output posted have now changed.

Comment: Maybe it would help to add a print at the *top* of your outer loop, something like `printf("Top of loop; i = %d\n", i);`.

Comment: You should put the `printf("i = %d\n", i);` (without indent) before the second loop

Comment: @Achal I modified it to find the mistake in the loops, so I removed everything related to the characters to focus on them. Here I only want to find the mistake in the loops.

Comment: I changed the code so it's complete and the variables' values are visible

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match what you wrote above. For the inner loop: Either 0 doesn't get printed (cause it's position 0) and 1 gets printed once or 0 gets printed once, but 1 then gets printed twice.

Additionally, if you want to get the non indented value above those of the inner loop, you'd have to put your loop after the unindented printf-statement.

Comment: Moving your print of `i` to the top of your outer loop almost gets you there. But the inner loop won't run at all when `i == 0`.  You could maybe change the inner loop to a `do`/`while` loop.

Comment: The `j` loop doesn't iterate on the first `i` loop. Apart from that the `i` doesn't change except where it is supposed to.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your answer helped me solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get code in a loop executed atleast once, you could use a do-while-loop. I went ahead and changed it for you. Additionally, printing an unindented `i` before the loop gets you to your desired output.

```
int position = 0;
int size = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    int j = 0;
    do {
        printf("    i = %d\n", i);
        j++;
    } while (j < position);

    position++;
}

printf("\n");
```

Edit: Ah, I see, you have changed your desired output yet again! This makes the condition of executing the code atleast nolonger necessary. A regular while-loop does the trick:

```
int position = 0;
int size = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    int j = 0;
    while (j < position) {
        printf("    i = %d\n", i);
        j++;
    }

    position++;
}

printf("\n");
```

Comment: I had forgot about the do while loop, thanks for the help! I had made a mistake while writing the desired output, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've created an odd variable loop condition with `position`. First lap in the `i` for loop, it skips the inner loop, then increases position by 1 and prints i = 0. Then next lap when `i` is 1, it executes the inner loop, and so on.

This would be why it is a bad idea to use an ever-changing condition in `for` loops - it makes the code much harder to understand.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: @AlexaN I have no idea what the purpose of this loop is, so I can't answer that. Looks like an artificial school book example rather than real code.

Comment: That may be because It removed everything about the real program to find why the loops were failing, don't worry, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the output of the variable `i` before the inner loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int position = 0;
    int size = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);

        for (int j = 0; j < position; j++)
        {
            printf("    i = %d\n", i);
        }

        position++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
i = 0
i = 1
    i = 1
i = 2
    i = 2
    i = 2
i = 3
    i = 3
    i = 3
    i = 3
```